# Authorize bash to access GitHub protected branch

Tags: bash, git, authorization, github-actions

<sup>*This might be a silly question, but here I am after two days of head banging*</sup>

I'm currently working on a GitHub Actions job, that would at some point `git push` to a protected branch (`master`, actually). However, once it gets to this step, the job fails with a "**You're not authorized to push**" error message:

[image: Error message]
<sub>*error code GH006*</sub>

In my situation, the first time it happened, it meant that the worker (CLI, `bash`) is not authorized at all. So I went to log it in a dedicated GitHub account, — and this is where I'm stuck for a couple of days now.

**So, how do I login to GitHub account via CLI?**

---

### The things I've tried:

#### Pushing to master manually

This works without errors, since the authorization is OK, — but it is obviously not automated, which is what I'm after.

A couple of details:

- I was using Windows 10, whereas the job is set up to run on `"ubuntu-18.04"`;
- I've removed all GitHub-related logins from Windows Credential Manager before performing `git push`, and set them up again via GitHub Login dialog window.

Manually pushing under unauthorized credentials fails, as expected.

#### `git remote set-url origin "https://$username:$token@github.com/my/repo"`

This didn't seem to give any effect. I've tried both setting URL of the existing remote and removing-than-adding remotes with different URLs, — both approaches seem to work (not work) the same.

None of the configurations below worked:

```
steps:
  - run: git remote set-url origin "https://$username:$token@github.com/my/repo"
  - run: git push origin master
```

```
steps:
  - run: git remote remove origin
  - run: git remote add origin "https://$username:$token@github.com/my/repo"
  - run: git fetch origin --all # with and without this step
  - run: git push origin master
```

#### `curl -u "$username:$token" https://api.github.com/user`

This is [suggested in the docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens), and it does succeed, but the login does not persist until `git push` — even if the pushing happens in the same step. I suspect, there might be a cookie-related solution, but I'm not sure how do they work in a non-browser environment. Also, I believe that this API is designed for different purposes.

Both of these configurations failed:

```
steps:
  # separate processes
  - run: curl -u "$username:$token" https://api.github.com/user
  - run: git push origin master
```

```
steps:
  # same process
  - run: |
      curl -u "$username:$token" https://api.github.com/user
      git push origin master
```

Comment: I don’t think you can turn it off using the CLI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`actions/checkout@v2` will now configure and persist authentication when setting the `token` input. You shouldn't need to configure the origin URL manually.

```
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      - name: Create a change
        run: echo "test" > test.txt
      - name: Commit change
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'Your Name'
          git config --global user.email 'your-username@users.noreply.github.com'
          git add -A
          git commit -m "Add test file"
          git push
```

According to [this comment](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/How-to-push-to-protected-branches-in-a-GitHub-Action/m-p/38172/highlight/true#M3246) on the GitHub forums, the PAT must be created from an admin/org owner account. A collaborator with write access is not enough to push to protected branches.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! One thing is that it was enough to give it a PAT with write access (the user has a "Writer" permission in org; their PAT is scoped to `repo_public`; user is specifically mentioned to be allowed to push to the protected branch).